# How to add new elements to existing XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have this problem with XML in C#.
I tried to add new elements to already existing .xml file with button, but when I click it nothing happens.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Filmovi>
  <Film ID="1">
    <Ime>Deadpool 2</Ime>
    <DatumPrikazivanja>08-06-2018</DatumPrikazivanja>
    <VrijemePrikazivanja>21:30</VrijemePrikazivanja>
    <Trajanje>119 min</Trajanje>
    <Redatelj>David Leitch</Redatelj>
    <GlavniGlumci>Ryand Reynolds, Josh Brolin</GlavniGlumci>
    <Opis>Foul-mouthed mutant mercenary Wade Wilson (AKA. Deadpool), brings together a team of fellow mutant rogues to protect a young boy with supernatural abilities from the brutal, time-traveling cyborg, Cable. </Opis>
    <PosterLink> E:kinoapp/posteri/deadpoolposter.jpg </PosterLink>
  </Film>
</Filmovi>
```

This is the code I tried.

```
private void dodajGumb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"E:\kinoapp\xml\filmovi.xml");
            doc.Element("Filmovi").Add(
                    new XElement("Film", new XAttribute("ID", IDtext.Text),
                    new XElement("Ime", imeText.Text),
                    new XElement("DatumPrikazivanja", datum.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")),
                    new XElement("VrijemePrikazivanja", vrijemeText.Text),
                    new XElement("Trajanje", trajanjeText.Text),
                    new XElement("Redatelj", redateljText.Text),
                    new XElement("GlavniGlumci", glumciText.Text),
                    new XElement("Opis", opisText.Text),
                    new XElement("PosterLink", Convert.ToString(posterText.Text))
            ));

            doc.Save("filmovi.xml"); 

        }
```

[picture of a form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPS9q.png)[image]

I don't get any errors or anything, it's just that nothing adds to the XML file. Any advice?

Comment: You aren't saving the original file.  Are you sure it isn't adding anything?

Comment: Give `Save()` the full path. Without a full path it's saving to the working directory of the application, which is almost certainly not E:\kinoapp\xml\. It's probably your bin\debug for the project. Look there for the altered filmovi.xml you just created

Comment: How you mean the original file? I'm sorry I'm a beginner.
After I click the button and I open the .xml file the new element I was trying to add isn't there.

Comment: @EdPlunkett that's it. i'm sure i tried that already, but i must have gotten something else wrong while i was trying all the combinations of code i could think of. thank you!

Comment: The original file being the file you opened to add new elements to?  You clearly aren't saving to the same file.  I'm voting to close as a typographical error as the issue wasn't actually an issue.